# What does the \x1a characters mean

Tags: php, mysql, ascii

What does the `\x1a` character mean and why does `mysql_real_escape_string` escape it?

From the documentation:

> mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

A ASCII Characters reference describes it as `Substitute character`, but this doesn't say much.

Comment: I believe `1A` is `Ctrl + Z` which is commonly used for EOF.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a Unicode [escape sequence, in hexadecimal (base 16)](https://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php). `\x1a` is the ["substitute" character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1a/index.htm).

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character

---

> Why does `mysql_real_escape_string` escape it?

[According to the documentation,](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html)

> Strictly speaking, MySQL requires only that backslash and the quote character used to quote the string in the query be escaped. `mysql_real_escape_string()` quotes the other characters to make them easier to read in log files.

Comment: Why does `mysql_real_escape_string` escape it?

Answer (score 16):

`\x1A` is the <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> control character. It is also EOF marker.

Answer (score 4):

`\x1a` is a [SUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) control character, used to mark end of a file (EOF).

Answer (score 2):

It is a hexadecimal escape sequence for the [SUB character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character).

Comment: Why does `mysql_real_escape_string` escape it?

Comment: Because MySQL travels through a network stream, and the EOF character may be interpreted to mean the end of the stream.

Comment: That's not the reason that the documentation cites.

Answer (score 0):

This is is because of an empty line et the eof file
the program try to read the values in the empty line and read \x1a